# json.JSONException on converting lang.string to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to create a registration page for an android app.i watched a few tutorials about it.in the tutorial, that programmer wrote this code and it worked for him. now the problem is it throws JSONException at my code.here is the code.

```
  Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String> 
  () {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                //this is the response from register.php
                    try {
                        Log.d("RESPONSE",response);
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success){
                            Intent intent0 = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent0);
                        }
                        else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();

                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "its here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };
```

when I press the REGISTER button it shows a Toast(it's in the catch part)
and throws 
json.JSONException: Value

and here is the Log.d("RESPONSE",response);result

**Warning**:  mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **/home2/amirrez2/public_html/register.php** on line **19**
                                                                     
                                                                     **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home2/amirrez2/public_html/register.php** on line **20**
                                                                     
                                                                     **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home2/amirrez2/public_html/register.php** on line **21**
                                                                     
                                                                     **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_store_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home2/amirrez2/public_html/register.php** on line **22**
                                                                     
                                                                     **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home2/amirrez2/public_html/register.php** on line **23**
                                                                     
                                                                     **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home2/amirrez2/public_html/register.php** on line **24**
                                                                     
                                                                     **Warning**:  mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **/home2/amirrez2/public_html/register.php** on line **12**
                                                                     
                                                                     **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home2/amirrez2/public_html/register.php** on line **13**
                                                                     
                                                                     **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home2/amirrez2/public_html/register.php** on line **14**
                                                                     
                                                                     **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **/home2/amirrez2/public_html/register.php** on line **15**
                                                                     {"success":true}

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the error log too.

Comment: It is because your service returns a string instead of JSON response try printing your response and verify.

Comment: @Abilash u mean on the php code?

Comment: Check your response is actual jsonobject data..

Comment: Show your response please.

Comment: use Logger to print your response in android and you can validate the JSON [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH im new on this so where should i look for response?

Comment: @Shayanebrahimzadeh response is the string from onResponse method. Check that value.

Comment: @Abilash can you please tell me more about it?

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH i know im asking more than what i should. but how can i check the value?

Comment: @Shayanebrahimzadeh Just add this line `Log.d("RESPONSE",response);` at first line in try function it will print the response & check that value is string or json. Copy response here and check here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Use the following method Log.d("RESPONSE",response)

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH thank u very much.it was helpful

Comment: @Abilash thank u very much it was a very helpful.

Comment: @Shayanebrahimzadeh Welcome glad to help..!

Comment: The issue is in your php file once it is fixed and it returns a proper JSON response your code will work properly.

Comment: @Abilash yeah fixed it tnq